# Find the best solution to get distance from point to triangle in 2D

Tags: javascript

I want to find the distance between point and triangle in 2D.
The only solution I came up to is to find distance to each side and take the smallest.
So I did a translation of point to each side plane, and used Pythagorean theorem:

```
function getAngle(from, to) {
    return Math.atan2(to.y - from.y, to.x - from.x);
}

function getDistance(from, to) {
    let a = from.x - to.x;
    let b = from.y - to.y;
    return Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b);
}

function getDistanceToTriangle(from, triangle) {
    function getDistanceToSide(sideX, sideY, sideAngle, sideWidth) {
        let angle = getAngle({x:sideX, y:sideY}, from) - sideAngle;
        let distance = getDistance({x:sideX, y:sideY}, from);
        let fromX = Math.cos(angle) * distance + sideX;
        let fromY = Math.sin(angle) * distance + sideY;

        let a = fromX - Math.max(Math.min(fromX, sideX + sideWidth), sideX);
        let b = fromY - sideY;              
        return Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b);
    }

    let abDistance = getDistanceToSide(triangle.ax, triangle.ay, triangle.abAngle, triangle.abWidth);
    let bcDistance = getDistanceToSide(triangle.bx, triangle.by, triangle.bcAngle, triangle.bcWidth);
    let caDistance = getDistanceToSide(triangle.cx, triangle.cy, triangle.caAngle, triangle.caWidth);

    return Math.min(Math.min(abDistance, bcDistance), caDistance);
}
```

Is any better / faster solution to solve this problem?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Cartesian_coordinates

Comment: Thanks! Seems I got it :)

Answer (score 1):

OK. I tried to implement the solution from the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Cartesian_coordinates) that [axiac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4265352/axiac) pointed out to me, and yes, it seems, now it is much more efficient:

```
function getDistanceToTriangle(from, triangle) {
    function getDistanceToSide(x1, y1, x2, y2, sideWidth) {
        return ((y2 - y1) * from.x - (x2 - x1) * from.y + x2 * y1 - y2 * x1) / sideWidth;
    }

    let abDistance = getDistanceToSide(triangle.ax, triangle.ay, triangle.bx, triangle.by, triangle.abWidth);
    let bcDistance = getDistanceToSide(triangle.bx, triangle.by, triangle.cx, triangle.cy, triangle.bcWidth);
    let caDistance = getDistanceToSide(triangle.cx, triangle.cy, triangle.ax, triangle.ay, triangle.caWidth);

    return Math.max(Math.max(abDistance, bcDistance), caDistance);
}
```

`sideWidth` of each side of triangle was pre calculated with `getDistance` function:

```
function getDistance(from, to) {
    let a = from.x - to.x;
    let b = from.y - to.y;
    return Math.sqrt(a*a + b*b);
}
```

For more efficiency some parts of formula can be pre calculated as well.